# complexity cost for which one is greater : determinant or eigen values?

Tags: matrices, matlab, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, computational-complexity, determinant

what is complexity cost for determining all of eigen values?
what is complexity cost for calculating determinant ?

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the determinant in $O(n^3)$ operations using Gaussian elimination. Finding eigenvalues cannot be done with rational operations because it is equivalent to finding roots of polynomials and there are no formulas for that for degree 5 or higher. Do you mean the complexity of finding approximations for eigenvalues?